# Do they make cord lit extension cords?

Tags: electrical, wiring, safety, outdoor

I am not looking for a specific product recommendation.  I am wondering if a product exists and what the technical name for it would be so I can find various manufactured products when doing search.  Apologies if this is still considered product recommendation.

### Background

I am looking to occasionally run an extension cord over a sidewalk during the overnight period.  There occasionally will be people out walking their dogs so I want to reduce the trip hazard potential by drawing attention to this glowing/lit cord passing over the ground.

The location is on Condo property and is part of the common elements.  As a result, no construction or alterations of common elements may occur without the Condo Boards approval.

### What I have tried

I did a bunch of google searches and I wind up either finding extension cords with lit connector ends or I found the LED strip lighting for computers and decorating rooms.

**Update**
Based on comments, I have also stumbled upon **ROPE LIGHTING** and garden string lighting which both appear very promising.  I have been informed that some rope lighting has connectors at both ends so you can either daisy chain ropes together or have an electrical device at the other end.  However its for low amperage.  Definitely close.

### Update II

I actually found the product while looking for something else.  Stumbled upon by blind luck.  Having said that, details are sparse and I am not even sure how to buy limited quantity as what I found seems to be a manufacturers site.  The term they are using is [LUMINOUS CABLES](https://www.omgevcable.com/ev-charging-cables/390.html).  I am curious if it is available for the NA market and how exactly is the power for the lighting supplied?  ie it only works with their level 1 charger?  Or is the lighting run by a separate module/plug and you can replace any J1772 cordage with it.

[image]

[image]

### Question

Do they make extension cords where the cable itself is lit?  If so what should I be using for search terms?

I am looking for something in the 50-100 ft range and 10 or 12 gauge.

Location:  Ontario, Canada

Comment: I would like to know if such a thing exists even outside of the physical requirements of the cable I am looking for

Comment: @knowitall my current back up plan would be to wrap LED strip lighting around it.  Place the little power brick in a weather proof box concept and see how it goes from there.

Comment: Charging EVs? They make rope lights, which could be zip-tie'd to the extension cord for the relevant section.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica yes, this is just like the garden string like concept I was thinking about.  I guess what I really want is a ROPE LIGHT EXTENSION CORD.  Kind of like a christmas tree light string with a plug at each end!  Thank you for the ROPE LIGHT term.  My google searches are coming up with items for your concept.

Comment: How much power are you trying to get down this cord? Many rope lights have "thru wires" intended for powering additional strings of rope lights end-to-end.  That can handle *a little bit* of power, like a bug zapper or camera or lamp.  An EV is right out!

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica LEVEL 1 EV charger.  So 120v - 12 amps sustained.  The extra heavy duty gauge I was looking at was to reduce the comments from the Condo board.  My unit's outdoor dedicated wall plug on a 15 amp circuit is just under 50' from my parking spot on the other side of a sidewalk.

Comment: Would make sure you have written permission from the local overloads to place the cord over the sidewalk first.  Most places that is a no-no.

Comment: can you tunnel under the sidewalk?

Comment: strip lights are stiff and fragile so i would use "fairy lights" instead; they are cheaper, much finer, more flexible, and weatherproof-ish.

Comment: Please revise your post to ask how to solve a problem and not ask for specific products. That's off topic here.

Comment: Code would require a protective cover much like knowitall has a example of, if someone damaged the cord and gets a shock guess who is responsible rope lighting would provide additional electrical hazards+ A motion light with a cover would be a good addition the light may dissuade a wood-be wire thief.

Comment: Forward Ed, is the ground yours or a community area?  If yours you could install a rigid pipe a few inches down and go under the sidewalk and install a ground level receptacle with a locking cover. I have installed this at a home without a garage / carport we also put the receptacle on a switch so it was only on when the owner turned it on , it’s amazing what some folks try and steal.

Comment: @EdBeal I do not currently have permission to trench through common element areas.  Unfortunately the sidewalk that runs between my small patch of yard and the parking area is all common element.  Also I cannot affix anything to fences or the building as they are all considered common elements.  To put in a motion sensing light, I would have to build a free standing structure in my yard that is high enough to reach over the fence and high enough that it is not blinding people as the walk along the sidewalk either.

Comment: @EdBeal I was wondering how temporary a setup would require such a protective cord device.  I am only looking at charging once every week or two.  I get most of my charging done at other locations usually.  Since the Condo by-laws state you are not allowed to leave things on common property overnight, I was planning on waiting until after midnight to plug in and then pick up it when I woke up the following day.  Also is this cord protector a US, Canada, or Common Sense requirement?

Comment: This is why I asked if it was community or yours it makes a difference, dropping a in ground box outlet simple 20 amp GFCI protected can be done if your space. this will not violate HOA rules it is not really visible, yes I have installed a couple but they were for electric mowers!!!

Comment: @isherwood My apologies, I did not consider this a product recommendation.  I thought product recommendations were questions like what is the best car for XXX, or what Program should I use to do XXX.  This question was broader than looking for a specific manufacturer, but looking for ANY manufacturer.  The example I think of is the Q:  Do they make self propelled camping trailers?  A: yes, they are called RVs in North America.

Comment: I'd be asking if a 100 foot 10 gauge cord is ok to have 1,440 Watts drawn down it and then go to bed.... Any charger I've ever seen had a NEMA plug on it to make sure you aren't fucking around, much like RVs. Presumably the car says *do not plug into an extension cord* ? It's basically a microwave or a space heater. I wouldn't put a turkey in a MW, plug it into an ext cord, and then go to bed.

Comment: ... or you have a NEMA 15 (standard) adapter, which is, 'see also' *how to set your RV on fire*.

Comment: Forward Ed a temporary use is all that cordage is allowed for and public areas covers are required.  Could you get away without it sure.

Comment: Product questions also include those seeking shopping assistance. Sometimes it's fair to ask what type of supplier would provide an item, but here it's fairly obvious that you need an electrical products company.

Answer (score 6):

I would use outdoor cord protection cover

that also prevents people falling over it, or steping on the cable it self.

In my neighborhood a lit cord would just attract attention, and dogs might bite it just because.

[image: cover]

Comment: I am aware of that solution but for other reason I was trying to avoid it.   I totally agree that its a good idea though...  Wonder if they make lit versions of those.

Comment: If yo want light, install two 12 Volt LED reflector lights on each end and the cord cover will light up in yellow.. As I said not in my neighborhood. It is not only good idea, it is required for safety

Comment: @ForwardEd You could always drill small holes in that yellow cover and mount small battery-powered LED lights under the cover with the light showing through the hole. A low-power LED light should easily run O/N on a couple of AA batteries, especially if in blinking mode. Easiest way to do this might be to get some cheap small flat battery-powered red tail lights for bicyclists.

Comment: @armand This may be going out in -15C to -20C weather so I think I would need to go with a small power adapter in lieu of batteries.  Though you got me thinking about a solar powered garden light string...at least for the warmer months

Comment: Bike lights are often used at such cold temps by hardy riders with studded tires :)  A "bunny" brand's lithium iron disulfide disposable AA batteries specs indicate "The recommended operating temperature range is -40°C to +60°C"

Comment: Yes, a neighbor who lives down a quiet cul-de-sac does that to charge their EV which parks on the street.

Comment: In my experience this is a far _greater_ trip hazard than the cord. The cord is much lower and can move with a foot to some extent. If this thing isn't noticed in the dark it's almost certainly going to take down a senior. The traction cleats exacerbate the problem.

Comment: @isherwood but required by code for temporary installation as the op has I was going to post the exact same

Comment: Yes, _to protect the cord_. This doesn't address the nature of the question, which is about trip hazards. Code probably requires _lighting_ where appropriate, too.

Comment: Funny the cord cover is listed to prevent tripping on a cord and to protect the cord their are others what are lower profile I would think as it is a requirement and allowed in egress locations of public buildings that on a sidewalk there would not be an issue at least legally but a cord and light is a legal issue.

Comment: Stumbled on City of Vancouver allowances for street side charging of EVs.  Along with getting a license, the homeowner must supply a cord protection device similar to this, and carry minimum $1M in insurance.

Answer (score 2):

If this is something you do often, then why not build a small frame that supports the wire overhead? Something you could set up and take down easily and not be a trip hazard?

Comment: Very possible that local rules prohibit doing that on public property.

Comment: Strikes me that even if it were allowed, an overhead structure would be an even bigger target for the local mischief makers than an extension cord laying on the ground.

Comment: Condo rules prohibit the installation off permanent structures on common elements without the permission from the board.  Based on my experience with Condo Boards this would not be permitted.  The board cannot make special case exemptions supposedly as they are not allowed to show favouratism, and you certainly do not want a hundred such apparatus to be showing up all over the property.

Comment: I actually considered sending it through the ground cover of the adjacent wild flower garden and up a large tree with branches that over hang adjacent parking spots.  I was thinking of letting the cord dangle from the opposite side. of the sidewalk.  Couple of problems were:  A) That it was too far away from my parking spot.  B) Would have resulted in a permanent set up on common elements (definite no no), C)  The cord would have been unsightly for other Condo Owners (ergo a no no), D)  pendulum effect on windy days.  E) holy hanna what happens when the tree falls down or loses the branch?

Answer (score 2):

> I am looking to occasionally run an extension cord over a sidewalk during the overnight period.

It is unlikely that you can do this, it is a public safety hazard. You should get approval from your town.

Assuming the town approves this tripping hazard then wrapping the cord in reflective tape and having a nearby light source to activate it could be one option.

Comment: Like the concept.  There is high pressure sodium light source all over the grounds that provide low level night lighting.

Comment: Just found out earlier today that the City of Vancouver allows for this if the home owner gets a license.  Part of the license states the home owner has a minimum $1M liability insurance and the City is covered by the insurance/homeowner accepts all responsibility.

Comment: @ForwardEd Well, good luck with that!